# org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Employees is not mapped

Tags: jpa-2.0

we have an application where mapping is done through orm.xml files and now trying add annotaitons. Is it  possible to have both combined.

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="disc" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>disc.jdbc.DataSource.OLTP</jta-data-source>

        <!--  List of Mapping files -->
        <mapping-file>META-INF/discCommon.orm.xml</mapping-file>
        <mapping-file>META-INF/discTerminology.orm.xml</mapping-file>

        <class>com.model.correspondence.Employees</class>
         <class>com.model.correspondence.AbstractEmployees</class>   
      </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

in entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST", schema="company") 
public class Employees extends AbstractEmployees{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID", unique=true, nullable = false)
    private long employeeId;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION",  nullable = false)
    private String description;
```

Serivceclass

```
private static final String SEARCH_FROM_ALL_EMPLOYEES= " select o from " +  Employees.class.getSimpleName()+ " o WHERE " +
    " upper(o.description) LIKE :desc";

Query query = entityManager.createQuery(SEARCH_FROM_ALL_EMPLOYEES);
        query.setParameter("desc", "%" + desc.toUpperCase() + "%");
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        List employeeList= query.getResultList();
```

orm.xml files are working but the annotation entity class are not getting mapped. Below is error

> Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Employees is not mapped [ select o from Employees o WHERE  upper(o.description) LIKE :desc]*
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:180)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:110)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:93)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:324)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3420)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3309)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try adding this line in your `persistence.xml`

```
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
```

Sometimes, because of different configuration at our projects, the classes generated  weren't ubicated in a path were JPA (and the implementation you used) can auto-scanning.

So, in my case, I used that line to tell to the JPA implementation that must map that classes I put in the `persistence.xml` and does't wait to the auto-scanning.

In that case, a possibility for your persistence.xml will be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="disc" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>disc.jdbc.DataSource.OLTP</jta-data-source>

        <!--  List of Mapping files -->
        <mapping-file>META-INF/discCommon.orm.xml</mapping-file>
        <mapping-file>META-INF/discTerminology.orm.xml</mapping-file>

        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <class>com.model.correspondence.Employees</class>
        <class>com.model.correspondence.AbstractEmployees</class>   
      </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I hope, this works for you...